# Can a push message sent by google cloud messaging be hidden from the app user?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I'm just going through the concept options of the Google Cloud Messaging System https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options and I saw this:

```
App behavior when receiving messages that include both notification and data payloads
depends on whether the app is in the background, or the foreground —essentially,
whether or not it is active at the time of receipt.
- When in the background, apps receive the notification payload in the notification tray,
  and only handle the data payload when the user taps on the notification.
- When in the foreground, your app receives a bundle with both payloads available.
```

Is it possible to send a push message to specific android device and then verify its content by the app's logic?
And then if the content is verified by the app and it's correct - notify the user, in other case stay silent, dismiss the push msg and don't even show the notification icon?
Thanks!

Comment: yes its possible. Don't create your notification when push message doesn't fulfill your requirement.

Comment: Why don't you try it and if you face any issue, we shall be happy to help.

Comment: just use a `data`payload instead of `notification`,and parse the content in your client code

Comment: It is possible, remember that the data on the payload is something that can be manipulated programmatically. You can choose to add logic on the `message` parameter in the payload depending on what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You have to track the gcm type, for what such gcm gets called, depend on that you can show & hide notifications.

Answer (score 0):

To show notification to user for push the control is in your hand only. Just apply the check that you want to and if the condition satisfies only then generate the notification.